# Length of line segment in a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Triangle ABC has $\vert AB\vert$= 2007 and $\vert AC \vert$ = 2015. The incircle of the triangle is tangent to AC and AB at E and F respectively, and P is the intersection point of EF and BC. Suppose B is the midpoint of CP. Compute the length $\vert BC \vert$.

Comment: What is the point $D$? Did you mean $B$?

Comment: I did mean B, sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 2):

So assuming $B=D$ you set the following notations:

$G$ the tangent point of the incircle with $BC$, $x=|BC|$ and
$$|AE|=|AF|=a\\
  |BF|=|BG|=b\\
  |CG|=|CE|=c$$

By Menelaüs theorem:
$$\frac{PB}{PC}\frac{EC}{EA}\frac{FA}{FB}=1$$
Thus you get: $\frac{1}{2}\frac{c}{a}\frac{a}{b}=1$
so $c=2 b$.

Now you have the following equations:
\begin{align}
a+c &=2015\\
a+b &=2007\\
b+c &=x
\end{align}
Thus $b=c-b=2015-2007=8$ and $x=3 b =24$

**Conclusion:** $|BC|=24$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is $|AD|$? If you meant $|AB|$, apply Menelaus' theorem and then form two very simple equations to find $|BF|$. If you don't know Menelaus' theorem, simply draw a line through $B$ parallel to $EF$.

Comment: You were faster. Plus you saw a nice way of getting around Menelaus.

Comment: Of course I was faster. I wrote only three sentences. And I gave a rough sketch of the solution(in the spirit of a hint since it seems to me that this is a more of a homework problem), while you wrote the full blown solution :D...

Comment: Yeah, I haven't thought about that. I hope I didn't spoil it.

Comment: It isn't a homework problem, I'm trying to teach myself geometry proofs and this is just a question I found on a PDF, but I wasn't able to find a solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tstock If that's the case, it is good to say it in your post. You can say 'I have been trying to solve it, but cannot figure this one out, I tried this and that but...'  or 'I am learning geometry on my own and came across this problem and I am stuck'... etc. People are then more responsive :)... Plus then they are not going to downvote or close your question.

Comment: @Futurologist, I'll definitely keep that in mind for next time. I'm pretty new to this site, so I'm still trying to figure out how everything works. Thanks!